# Ошибка file_get_contents(link) PHP

Tags: php, telegram

[![Мой код:][1]][1]

```
  $message = "Дата получения СМС: " . date("d-m-Y H:i");
    
function request($method, $tokken, $params = array()) {
      if (!empty($params) ) {
            $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$tokken."/".$method."?".http_build_query($params)."";
      }
      else {
            $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$tokken."/".$method."";
      }
      return json_decode(file_get_contents( urlencode($url) ), JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY);
};

$keyboard = array(
      array(
         array('Оплачено'=>':oplacheno:','callback_data'=>'{"action":"oplacheno","count":0,"text":":oplacheno:"}'),
         array('Не оплачено'=>':not_oplacheno:','callback_data'=>'{"action":"not_oplacheno","count":0,"text":":not_oplacheno:"}'),
      )
);

request("sendMessage", "тут мой токен", array( // токен бота
      'chat_id' => "-491886336", // ID твой 
      'text' => $message,
      'disable_web_page_preview' => false,
      'reply_markup' => json_encode(array('inline_keyboard' => $keyboard))
));
```

Получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.telegram.org/bot1405228953:AAFvZFJLsXuD4pFsbAjJauYHiRymWblz1D0/sendMessage?chat_id=-491886336&text=%F0%9F%93%86%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D0%A1%D0%9C%D0%A1%3A+24-12-2020+10%3A10&disable_web_page_preview=0&reply_markup=%7B%22inline_keyboard%22%3A%5B%5B%7B%22%5Cu041e%5Cu043f%5Cu043b%5Cu0430%5Cu0447%5Cu0435%5Cu043d%5Cu043e%22%3A%22%3Aoplacheno%3A%22%2C%22callback_data%22%3A%22%7B%5C%22action%5C%22%3A%5C%22oplacheno%5C%22%2C%5C%22count%5C%22%3A0%2C%5C%22text%5C%22%3A%5C%22%3Aoplacheno%3A%5C%22%7D%22%7D%2C%7B%22%5Cu041d%5Cu0435+%5Cu043e%5Cu043f%5Cu043b%5Cu0430%5Cu0447%5Cu0435%5Cu043d%5Cu043e%22%3A%22%3Anot_oplacheno%3A%22%2C%22callback_data%22%3A%22%7B%5C%22action%5C%22%3A%5C%22not_oplacheno%5C%22%2C%5C%22count%5C%22%3A0%2C%5C%22text%5C%22%3A%5C%22%3Anot_oplacheno%3A%5C%22%7D%22%7D%5D%5D%7D): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in /profiles/g/gl/gli/glitch/my_site.ua/merchant/sms_x.php on line 32
```

PS: Извиняюсь за такой формат вопроса (скрином), просто так удобнее.
PPS: И за названия переменных тоже)

Comment: Так-же пробовал сделать так:

file_get_contents( urlencode($url) )

Comment: Пожалуйста, вставь код __текстом__. И да, код картинкой __никому не удобен__.

Comment: Вставил код `кодом`

Comment: ошибка ошибкой, а ответ то какой приходит. в теле ответа нет описания ошибки что ли?